# Fail to set EEST timezone

Tags: linux, timezone, date

I have a server which is set to `EEST` timezone (East European Summer Time). I'm trying to configure another server to this timezone, but I fail to find appropriate timezone in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall `tzdata`

**ubuntu** - `apt-get install --reinstall tzdata`

**Centos**  - `yum install tzdata`

List of [timezones](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization/3.0/html/REST_API_Guide/appe-REST_API_Guide-Timezones.html)

Answer (score 0):

Typically you set the correct time zone for a **region/city** and that will subsequently set your local time to the correct summer resp. winter time offset on the correct dates. AFAIK EEST is not a valid time zone name. Use the one of the cities in the [countries that observe EEST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_European_Summer_Time) such as Helsinki or Tallinn

Change the timezone with the systemd utility  [`timedatectl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html)

To list all available time zones:

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

To actually change the time zone, (as root or using `sudo`):

```
timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Helsinki
```